# IETE Paper LaTeX template

Tags: article, abstract

I have downloaded a .tex file which is a template for IETE research paper. But there is some problem in title and abstract section, which I am not able to rectify. Can anybody please help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in anticipation. Code is as follows

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IETEJR}
\begin{document}

**\title{Template for submission of papers to IETE Journal of Research}
\author{ First A. Author, Second B. Author, Jr., and Third C. Author\\
\vspace*{0.05em}\\\small F. A. Author is with the National Institute of Standards and Technology,\\\small Boulder, CO 80305 USA (corresponding author to provide phone: 303-555-5555;\\\small fax: 303-555-5555; e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov). \\
    \small S. B. Author, Jr., was with Rice University, Houston, TX 77005 USA.\\\small He is now with the Department of Physics, Colorado State University,\\\small Fort Collins, CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu).\\
    \small T. C. Author is with the Electrical Engineering Department,\\\small University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 80309 USA, on leave from the \\\small National Research Institute for Metals,\\\small Tsukuba, Japan (e-mail: author@nrim.go.jp).}
\twocolumn{
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    Fill the text from your manuscript in different sections.   ...
    \end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
About six to fifteen key words or phrases in alphabetical order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, visit http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani_prod/keywrd98.txt
\end{keywords}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]**
\section{INTRODUCTION}

Fill the text from your manuscript
\section{SECTION TWO}
\subsection{Sub-section Head Style}
Fill the text from your manuscript
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Fill the text from your manuscript

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Fill the text from your manuscript in different sections. 
\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Fill the text from your manuscript in different sections. 


\section{CONCLUSION}
The conclusion goes here.



%%\appendices
%\section{Proof of the First Zonklar Equation}
%Appendix one text goes here.
%
%\section{}
%Appendix two text goes here.


% use section* for acknowledgement
\section*{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}


The authors would like to thank...
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{1}R. Roy, and T. Kailath, “ESPRIT\_estimation of signal parameters via rotational invariance techniques,” IEEE Trans. Acoust. Speech Signal Process, Vol. 37, no. 7, pp. 984-95, Jul. 1989.

\end{thebibliography}

\section*{Note}\bf\large Manuscript length should be limited up to 10 pages including figures, tables, references, author’s bio and photo etc. After final checks, if the typeset manuscript exceeds 06 pages length, the author will be charged (after 06) per page @ Rs.1,000/- (for Indian Authors) and 50 USD (for Foreign Authors).
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The class `IETEJR` is needed for this. You could add a link for that.

Comment: 1. The `{` of `\twocolumn{` is never closed. 2. random `]**` in the code. 3. You can use `@` only within `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` in a tex file.

Comment: @dexteritas I don't see any comands with `@` names?

Comment: the `\twocolumn{` is intended to be `\twocolumn[` so that the `[` matches the `]` lower down

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `@` is in `@twocolumnfalse` environment.

Comment: @dexteritas but that would be unaffected by `\makeatletter`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, ok. You're right.

Comment: Can anybody please upload the latex template for IETE Review article?